# Are custom primitives supported for DFS over spark EntitySets?

Tags: apache-spark, primitive, entityset

From reading the spark guide, it's unclear to me whether it's possible to perform DFS with custom primitives when using a spark ES. I understand that there are limitations in what kind of primitives may be compatible over spark ES, but not whether it may be possible to add custom compatible primitives of my own. Any clarity on this would be very helpful, thank you.

I tried reading the docs / guide, and I was hoping to see more discussion on the use of custom primitives over spark. I didn't see them mentioned as not supported, so I decided to ask here.